# Yii views - Best way to solve a common scenario - Using Layouts?

Tags: php, templates, yii

Let's say you have a homepage that it's different (but not totally) from the rest of your site pages.

It's clear that we should create a layout for all secondary pages.

It's not so clear, however, how should we deal with the homepage here?

Because, if we make a conditional on the layout, telling something like:
If it's not the home page, use this, otherwise use that.

It's not at all friendly to maintain if, on the future, we have other pages that should also be different then homepage. If not this, and if not that, and if that, then ... :s

I believe it's on this situations that design patterns exist - but wish one?

My question is:
What would be a nice way to handle this?
Should we have two layouts defined? One for homepage and another for all the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes definitely make two layouts. Override the layout to use in case of the homepage in the action function in the controller:

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/home';
```

Comment: but the fact that the header and the footer on homepage are not totally different from all other pages (it only changes the colors or one image), would that be overkill ?

Comment: You can make separate header and footer files and include them from both layouts. Or if it's really just an image that's different or something like that, store the stuff that varies in a variable (set a default), write your layout pretending this variable is set, and overwrite that variable from your action. The layout starts rendering only after the controller finishes executing so you can set and overwrite these bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications. At least I get an idea about where should I go.